# Does a defendant in a criminal misdemeanor trial have to show up for announcement?

Tags: criminal-law, texas, rules-of-court, pro-se, court

I noticed that for speeding tickets and class C misdemeanors in our county court in Texas, the court will many times schedule an announcement repeatedly.

If a defendant shows up for the announcement and announces ready for trial, the court will then set another announcement for a month away. And the process will sometimes repeat itself for month after month for years.

My first thoughts were that those courts are very crowded and a minor offense like that just doesn't always get scheduled for trial due to other more important offenses taking the place in line. But the end result seems as if the court is trying to get the defendants who sometimes are Pro Se to just 'give up' because of spending so much time in court but not actually getting a trial.

What would be the worst that could happen if the defendant doesn't show up? Would the court just take it as a default announcement of 'ready for trial' or would it issue a warrant for the arrest of the defendant?

This is a trial 'de novo' and was tried in a municipal court prior to this one. 
For some strange reason, one of the trials I'm interested in also wound up in a court that normally only hears civil cases. I am also wondering why it was placed into a civil court being heard by a judge that normally only does civil trials.

Comment: This is highly jurisdiction specific, even to the individual court level. What county is this in?

Comment: Since this is a class C misdemeanor in County Court, I'm assuming this is an appeal. If it's not, then your case is being heard in the Justice or Municipal Court, and it should be tried in order of age (with limited preference to matters involving victims under 14).

Comment: It could be an appeal or it could not. In Texas appeals from a non court-of-record are tried 'de novo' and the prior trial, if any, had no bearing on the new trial. It can get to the county court by either an appeal or by the defendant simply sending a notarized letter and an appeal bond to the lower court.

I clarified the question to be in line with what you are asking. But yes, the ones I've seen this happen in are all trials 'de novo' coming from JP or municipal courts.

Comment: This particular case is in Denton county.